# Bootstrap tooltip not working with Bootstrap icon

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I am trying to use bootstrap tooltip on bootstrap icons, and this is my code:

```
   <body>
            <script>
                const tooltipTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')
                const tooltipList = [...tooltipTriggerList].map(tooltipTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl))
            </script>
            <p>File uploaded successfully</p>
            <p>File Name: {{name}}</p>
            <p>Total Values: {{i}}</p>
            <table class="styled-table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Key</th>
                    <th>Value</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {% for key, value in items %}
                    {% if key in desired_key %}
                        {% if key in result %}
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ key }}
                                <i class="bi bi-info-circle" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" data-bs-title="Tooltip on top" >
                                </i>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                            <table class="inner-table">
                                {% for k, v in result[key].items() %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{ k }}</td>
                                    <td>{{ v }}</td>
                                </tr>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        {% else %}
                        <tr>
                            <td >{{ key }} 
                                <i class="bi bi-info-circle">
                                </i>
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ value }}</td>
                        </tr>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </tbody>
            </table>
            
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
            <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-mQ93GR66B00ZXjt0YO5KlohRA5SY2XofN4zfuZxLkoj1gXtW8ANNCe9d5Y3eG5eD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        </body>
```

I also have links in head tag:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />
```

The script in the body tag was available on the Bootstrap website itself. Does anyone know why it's not working?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. There are a couple of questions with similar requests but none have helped.

Comment: are you using python flask? you might add that tag as well, even though it's not really related to it, but it might be helpful..

Comment: Sure @traynor will do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script runs before the content is parsed, so run it *after* all the content is parsed by wrapping it in a listener. Try this:

```
<script>

addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {

    const tooltipTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')
    const tooltipList = [...tooltipTriggerList].map(tooltipTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl))

});

</script>
```

**EDIT** pure example:

```html
<body>
  <script>
    addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {

      const tooltipTriggerList = document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="tooltip"]')
      const tooltipList = [...tooltipTriggerList].map(tooltipTriggerEl => new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl))

    });
  </script>

  <p>File uploaded successfully</p>
  <p>File Name: {{name}}</p>
  <p>Total Values: {{i}}</p>
  <table class="styled-table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Key</th>
        <th>Value</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for key, value in items %} {% if key in desired_key %} {% if key in result %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ key }}
          <i class="bi bi-info-circle" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" data-bs-title="Tooltip on top">
                                </i>
        </td>
        <td>
          <table class="inner-table">
            {% for k, v in result[key].items() %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ k }}</td>
              <td>{{ v }}</td>
            </tr>
            {% endfor %}
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      {% else %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ key }}
          <i class="bi bi-info-circle">
                                </i>
        </td>
        <td>{{ value }}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endif %} {% endif %} {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-mQ93GR66B00ZXjt0YO5KlohRA5SY2XofN4zfuZxLkoj1gXtW8ANNCe9d5Y3eG5eD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css" />
</body>
```

Comment: Hi, I did what you suggested, that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I've added an example with pure HTML, and, as you can see, it's working fine. Can you specify which framework you are using, it might be something to do with that, then

Comment: also, you're missing `data-bs-toggle="tooltip"...` in the else block of the code